# how to iterate an if statement without call all comparisons?

Tags: python-3.x

I have some fixed variables i want to compare with some user inputs. Based on the outcome I want to print a result, but how to compare variables without calling to many if statements and having to compare every single one with each other?

```
#Nutrition Class and methods

class Nutrition():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pro = pro
        self.vit = vit
        self.carb = carb
        self.fat = fat
        self.mineral = mineral

    def comp_nut(self, pro, vit, fat, carb, mineral):
        if(self.pro >= req_pro) and (self.vit>= req_vit) and (self.fat >= req_fat) and (self.carb >= req_carb) and (self.mineral >= req_min):
            print("You are healthy")
        elif (self.pro >= req_pro) and (self.vit>= req_vit) and (self.fat >= req_fat) and (self.carb >= req_carb) and (self.mineral < req_min):
            print("Mineral is low!")
            print("Require Amount is "+ str(req_min))
        elif (self.pro >= req_pro) and (self.vit>= req_vit) and (self.fat >= req_fat) and (self.carb < req_carb) and (self.mineral >= req_min):
            print("Carb is low!")
            print("Require Amount is "+ str(req_carb))
        elif (self.pro >= req_pro) and (self.vit>= req_vit) and (self.fat < req_fat) and (self.carb >= req_carb) and (self.mineral >= req_min):
            print("Fat is low!")
            print("Require Amount is "+ str(req_fat))
        elif (self.pro >= req_pro) and (self.vit < req_vit) and (self.fat >= req_fat) and (self.carb >= req_carb) and (self.mineral >= req_min):
            print("Vitamin is low!")
            print("Require Amount is "+ str(req_vit))
        elif (self.pro < req_pro) and (self.vit>= req_vit) and (self.fat >= req_fat) and (self.carb >= req_carb) and (self.mineral >= req_min):
            print("Protein is low!")
            print("Require Amount is "+ str(req_pro))
        else:
           print('More than 1')

# User Input

pro = int(input("Enter Protein: "))
vit = int(input("Enter Vitamin: "))
fat = int(input("Enter Fat: "))
carb = int(input("Enter Carbs: "))
mineral = int(input("Enter Mineral: "))
```

Comment: Why do you use so many `elif`s, and why do you keep checking each variable?

Comment: idk, thought thats what to be done, but alright remove it

Answer (score 1):

Test one thing at a time, like so:

```
def comp_nut(self, pro, vit, fat, carb, mineral):
    if (self.mineral < req_min):
        print("Mineral is low!")
        print("Require Amount is "+ str(req_min))
    elif (self.carb < req_carb):
        print("Carb is low!")
        print("Require Amount is "+ str(req_carb))
    elif (self.fat < req_fat):
        print("Fat is low!")
        print("Require Amount is "+ str(req_fat))
    elif (self.vit < req_vit):
        print("Vitamin is low!")
        print("Require Amount is "+ str(req_vit))
    elif (self.pro < req_pro):
        print("Protein is low!")
        print("Require Amount is "+ str(req_pro))
    else:
        print("You are healthy.")
```

This prints the first message for which the deficiency check succeeds, or "You are healthy." if all checks fail.

Comment: I feel so ashame! Thank you, this works as how i wanted it to!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeating all the fields every time, I would do something like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# Use a namedtuple so that we don't have to write __init__()
# and so that all the field names are stored in _fields.
class Nutrition(namedtuple('Nutrition', 'protein vitamin fat carb mineral')):

    # List of minimum requirement per each
    # field (these are random numbers)
    min_requirements = {
        'protein': 50,
        'vitamin': 60,
        'fat': 120,
        'carb': 30,
        'mineral': 40,
    }

    def check(self):
        healthy = False

        # Instead of checking the fields one by one,
        # use a loop over _fields.
        for field in self._fields:
            value = getattr(self, field)
            expected = self.min_requirements[field]
            if value < expected:
                print('{} is low!'.format(field.capitalize()))
                print('Required amount is {}'.format(expected))
                healthy = False

        if healthy:
            print('You are healthy')
```

Example usage:

```
n = Nutrition(
    protein=int(input('Enter Protein: ')),
    vitamin=int(input('Enter Vitamin: ')),
    fat=int(input('Enter Fat: ')),
    carb=int(input('Enter Carbs: ')),
    mineral=int(input('Enter Mineral: ')),
)

n.check()
```

This has the advantage that, if you want to add/remove a field, it's a trivial change. Moreover, if you want to add more complex conditions (e.g. checking the maximum instead of just the minimum), that's also a trivial change.

I used [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) mostly for laziness. This has the side effect that your fields are read-only, but you can achieve the same result trivially even without namedtuple.